# EmailMessage in EWS Managed API: The From Field

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I am using the Exchange Services Managed API.... I am able to send emails just fine with it, but is there a way to change the displayed From field when the email is sent....

Currently we have a default user called DoNotReply@xxxxxxx.com. When ever I send the email it shows up in the from field as DoNotReply.

Can I change that in code?

I tried using:

```
EmailMessage emailMessage = new EmailMessage(service);
emailMessage.From="xxxxx xxxxx xxxxx";`
```

But that doesn't seem to change anything.  So, is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up asking the Exchange admin to just change the display name for DoNotReply email

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the "Send as" permission for the email address you want to use. And you cannot use an email address which is not local to your organization.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676368.aspx